# "You’re gonna make the same if you do as good a job" meaning

Tags: phrases, american-english

For one of the question trump was asked. what do you think about women's equality ?

then he says

"You’re gonna make the same if you do as good a job"

I couldn't understand the meaning. Can someone explain me ?

Comment: It will need a bit more context. Are they talking about a mistake?

Comment: @marcellothearcane ...  _make_ as in "make money". It's an Americanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most confusing part here for an English learner is that make has [a lot of different meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make). One meaning is to "earn" (for instance money): "13: to gain (something, such as money) by working, trading, or dealing", example "make a living" (Merriam-Webster).

So "make the same" here means "earn the same amount". The rest of the sentence should be obvious: "women will earn the same amount as men if they do a job as well as men do it".